# JavaScript retrieve asynchronous data from an array

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, callback, promise

*Edit* Added actual code in addition to conceptual one way below.
Following is the structure I'm trying to implement async array access to.

```
for (p = 0; p < myList.length ; p++){ 
    for (k = 0; k < RequestList.length; k++){
        if (RequestList[k].name === myList[p].name){
            data = RequestList[k].data;
            //process data
            return //only intention is to exit if made use of the stored data
        }
    }
    // if mylist.name is not in the Requestlist
    // make the async request for it then push to RequestList array 
    // so the next time this name instance appears we use the previous data
    $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            index: p,
            success: function(aData) {
                   let obj = {
                   name : myList[index].name,   
                   data = aData.property //....
                   }
                   RequestList.push(obj);
                   //process data
            }
}
```

Conceptual explanation below here

```
var dataArray = []

for loop
```

first loop iteration

```
value = 5
dogdata = //ajax api request to dog
//attempt to store this data for later use
dataArray[1].name = "dog" 
dataArray[1].data = //async request fills this index with dog data
//process dogdata with value 5
```

second loop iteration

```
value = 3
catdata = //ajax api request to cat
//need data for cat and there are no cat named objects in the dataArray so
dataArray[2].name = "cat"
dataArray[2].data = //async request fills this index with cat data
//process catdata with value 3
```

third loop iteration

```
value = 8
//need data for dog but there is an object named dog at dataArray[1]
//so reach out to that instead of a new request
dogdata = dataArray[1].data // empty
//process dog data with value 8 this time!
```

obviously dogdata ends up being empty since first async call is not successfull yet

so when the dataArray[1]'s request is successful I want this to be handled with that request response while not blocking the whole loop

Possibly callback to first request's success here or a promise resolve here could be useful.

fourth loop iteration

```
//need data for monkey and there are no monkey named objects in the array so
dataArray[3].name = "monkey"
dataArray[3].data = //async request fills this with monkey data

//.... goes on like this for many iterations
```

Comment: You need to provide more _actual_ code. The question is too abstract at this point to be answered, because there's whole bunch of ways to achieve asynchronosity and the answers will very respectively.

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a promise. This will allow you to make separate ajax request and perform some functionality without blocking.

Comment: Need to see more code before working up a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
var mylist = [], dataArray = new Array(mylist.length), callCount = 0, callbackCounts = 0;
function getAsyncData(request, index, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'GET',
        url: request.url,
        index: index,
        success: function (aData) {
            let obj = {
                name: myList[index].name,
                data: aData.property
            };
            dataArray[index] = obj;
            callback();
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('error for ' + myList[index].name);
            callback();
        }
    });
}
function allDataLoaded() {
    //all data loaded
}
myList.forEach(function (listItem, idx) {
    var found = dataArray.some(function (el) {
        return el.name === listItem.name;
    });
    if (!found) {
        callCount++;
        getAsyncData(listItem, idx, function () {
            callbackCounts++;
            if (callbackCounts === callCount) {
                allDataLoaded();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a starting idea but the problem here is there is no fixed number of callBackcounts.
Request list's length could be 10 and all 10 of them could be different requests or all 10 could be the same request.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented this and it worked out good but I'd probably still rather using a promise based structure because It feels somewhat better not to do all the loading pre=process.

Appreciate the help though this will work perfectly until I figure out how to do the alternative structure!